# CakePHP 3 - How to use Trim() before validation NotEmpty?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My form validate empty fields, but if the user use "space", the validation handle how one character.. How to use Trim() in Model-Table for it not happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have a title column in Posts table and you want to trim title before validating.

put following code in src\Model\Table\PostsTable.php

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data)
    {
        $data['title'] = trim($data['title']);
    }
```

and add following two lines at the top of src\Model\Table\PostsTable.php

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked, if the spaces are saved in the database when you only use the beforeMarshal method? I tried this solution as well, but the entity itself was still containing the spaces. I saw this when there was another error triggered. So I think to surely remove the spaces, you have to call `$this->request->data['fieldname'] = trim($this->request->data['fieldname']);` in the Controller BEFORE using patchEntity to validate the submitted data. Maybe I'm wrong, but if you enter Space-Space-Character "  abc" this will not remove the spaces when the form is shown again with the error message?

Comment: No, I tried and the leading space was trimmed and then saved.

Answer (score 2):

I like to trim data in general for all requests.
This asserts that nonsense whitespace added does not make the validation unfunctional:

```
public function startup(Event $event) {
    // Data preparation
    if (!empty($this->Controller->request->data) && !Configure::read('DataPreparation.notrim')) {
        $this->Controller->request->data = $this->trimDeep($this->Controller->request->data);
    }
    if (!empty($this->Controller->request->query) && !Configure::read('DataPreparation.notrim')) {
        $this->Controller->request->query = $this->trimDeep($this->Controller->request->query);
    }
    if (!empty($this->Controller->request->params['pass']) && !Configure::read('DataPreparation.notrim')) {
        $this->Controller->request->params['pass'] = $this->trimDeep($this->Controller->request->params['pass']);
    }
```

So maybe use such a component hook to clean your data prior to using it anywhere in your controller or model layer.

Source 2.x: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/2.x/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php#L45-L57

Source 3.x: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php#L25-L34

Comment: This is for cakephp 2.x, will be to works cake 3? I didn't read all yet, but I'd have to create one component for each model that I want to validate?

Comment: You should be able to find the corresponding Cake3 branch in the same repo on your own..

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `beforeMarshal` in every model if you want to trim each record.

here is the working code

```
// Include use statements at the top of your file.
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;

// In a table or behavior class
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $data[$key] = trim($value);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the official reference of cakephp
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities

Answer (score -1):

You could use [beforeRules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforerules) callback and use trim () before data is validated.

Comment: Sorry, but can you give me a example using beforeRules?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [beforeRules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforerules) callback and use trim () before data is validated.

**Edit:**
A simple example:

```
public function beforeRules($event, $entity, $options, $operation){
    $entity->set ('yourFieldname', trim ($entity->get ('yourFieldname')));
    return parent:: beforeRules($event, $entity, $options, $operation);
```

Put this in your table class.

Comment: I am sorry i just edited my Post on smartphone and it is a new answer? Don't get what i did wrong?

Comment: `beforeRules` happens _after_ validation rules have been applied, and _before_ table rules are applied. What you maybe ment is [**`beforeMarshall`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal).